# What is the grammatical function of 'where to meet them' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, indirect-question

What is the grammatical function of 'where to meet them' in the sentence:

> Tell us where to meet them.

Is it an object of the verb? It is not a noun phrase and doesn't look like a typical object.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the question. Please provide more details. (Note that the title of the question doesn't seem to ask the same thing as the body of the question.)

Comment: Is the entire sentence "Tell us where to meet them," and you're asking the function of "Tell us" in that sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinitival interrogative clause with interrogative word *where* fronted - compare with declarative infinitival:

> *to meet them **where***  [declarative]
>
> ***where*** *to meet them* [interrogative]

These usually have the force of directives - *where we should meet them* (CaGEL p985)

> **Where should we meet them**? [interrogative]
>
> Where are we **to meet them**? [declarative infinitival]
>
> Did they tell us **where to meet them**? [interrogative infinitival]

As far as clause structure is concerned, the function of *where to meet them* is that of complement to the verb *tell*.

Answer (score -1):

*Tell* is the verb.

*us* is the indirect object

*where to meet us* is adverbial

You can see this by paraphrasing it as, "Tell to us about the meeting place."

Compare with, "Tell us quickly" - **Verb:indirect object:adverb**